# Первая картинка в цикле идёт unknown

Tags: javascript

Есть маленький скрипт ,который делает подобие анимации. Я как человек мало разбирающий в js , прошу помощи. Первая картинка идёт unknown , а остальное всё идёт по циклу. Картинки , такой не задавал.

```js
var images = new Array();
    var i = 1;

    images[1] = 'testlogo.png';
    images[2] = 'test1.png';
    images[3] = 'test2.png';
    images[4] = 'test3.png';
    images[5] = 'test4.png';

function viewImages() {

        document.getElementById("img_main").src = images[i];
        if (i != images.length - 1) {
          i++;
          setTimeout("viewImages()",800);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не "unknown", a "undefined". Однако, код, который Вы привели в вопросе, этого не делает.

```js
var images = new Array();
var i = 1;

images[1] = 'testlogo.png';
images[2] = 'test1.png';
images[3] = 'test2.png';
images[4] = 'test3.png';
images[5] = 'test4.png';

function viewImages() {

  document.getElementById("img_main").src = images[i];
  document.getElementById("img_main").alt = images[i];
  if (i != images.length - 1) {
    i++;
    setTimeout(viewImages, 800);
  }
}

viewImages();
```

```html
<img id="img_main" />
```

Вероятно, код, работу которого Вы наблюдаете, начинает с `i` равного нулю. Индексация массивов в javascript-е начинается с нуля:

```js
var images = new Array();
var i = 0;

images[0] = 'testlogo.png';
images[1] = 'test1.png';
images[2] = 'test2.png';
images[3] = 'test3.png';
images[4] = 'test4.png';

function viewImages() {

  document.getElementById("img_main").src = images[i];
  document.getElementById("img_main").alt = images[i];
  if (i != images.length - 1) {
    i++;
    setTimeout(viewImages, 800);
  }
}

//viewImages();
```

```html
<img id="img_main" />
```

---

*Update*

Поставьте в разметке

```
<img id="img_main" src="testlogo.png"/>
```

а не

```
<img id="img_main" src=""/>
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Comment: А так же, как я и говорил unknown . Вот сайт, увидите сами . http://l37-195-222-8.novotelecom.ru